# Does InnoDB use ROW locks when using UPDATE without a where clause

Tags: mysql, database, locks

I have a question about the locks on InnoDb Tables. If i understand the documentation correctly, InnoDB uses ROW locks when performing an UPDATE statement.

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `info` TEXT NULL,
  `deactivated` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Due to the size of the table this statement:

```
UPDATE tbl_name set deactivated = 1
```

can take up to 60 seconds.

During that time it happens that other processes want to INSERT another row into table_1.
Those processes have to wait for the UPDATE to be finished as the table is using the MyISAM engine which locks the whole table.

Now for a solution I'd imagine i just have to change the DB Engine to InnoDB to enable ROW locks rather than table locks.

My question now is: do i have to specify a WHERE clause in the UPDATE statement to force InnoDb to use row locks? Like so:

```
UPDATE tbl_name set deactivated = 1 WHERE deactivated IS NULL
```

Or does InnoDB handle the UPDATE on a ROW basis regardless of the existance of a WHERE clause?
Also due to the Table having an auto_increment column, does that change the way InnoDb handles locks?

Comment: Have you tried testing it?

Comment: INNODB locks all ROWS. you can test it. create 2 connections. start on the first your query and execute this on the second: SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; Then you can see that INNODB look a range of ROWS